Extract a class from a static method
Given a function which is a staticmethod of a class, is there a way to extract the parent class object from this?
class A:
   @staticmethod
   def b(): ...

...
f = A.b
...

assert get_parent_object_from(f) is A

I can see this buried in the __qualname__, but can't figure out how to extract this.
The function get_parent_object_from should have no knowledge of the parent class A.

To what end? Please give some context to help avoid the XY problem.

In some code b is consumed, and it needs to be a regular function, without any implicit self parameter. (This is why I can't do a class instance's function). However, I want to wrap up some type information into this function and some other bits of state). I can assign to the function with b.something = ..., but would prefer this to be held in the type in some manner.

IMHO, there is obvious contradiction that it needs to be static method and in the same time it has to wrap type and state bits. Maybe, just maybe, you need a class method?

Well, a __qualname__ is sufficient (under normal circumstances) to extract the owning class. Given a __qualname__ my.module.Class.method, split this using str.split with . as the separator, then call getattr starting from sys.modules["my"] until you reach the second-to-last name segment.

@dROOOze Yes, although it's worth noting that those abnormal circumstances include classes dynamically defined in a function scope and classes whose names are explicitly deleted from the defining namespace.

@blhsing I'm more thinking of situations like C extensions where the __qualname__ isn't populated correctly or doesn't actually represent a dotted name that exists in a Python package hierarchy. I can't imagine a useful situation where you'd need to extract a dynamically-defined class (whose identity changes every time a function is called), or trying to extract information off a deliberately deleted class; class introspection is normally about pulling out static information invariant to the Python session.

@blhsing - The class I am trying to extract is a dynamically defined class (inheriting from some statically defined base class).

@oliversm OK, so __qualname__ won't work for you. But does a custom static method descriptor work for you?

@blhsing - It looks like it should work for my purposes.

One approach would be to use a custom static method descriptor that sets the owner class as an attribute of the wrapped function:
class StaticMethod(staticmethod):
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.__wrapped__.owner = owner

class A:
   @StaticMethod
   def b(): ...

f = A.b
assert f.owner is A

Demo here
